# How to prevent Emacs from setting an undo boundary?

Tags: emacs, elisp, undo

I've written an Emacs Lisp function which calls a shell command to
process a given string and return the resulting string.  Here is a
simplified example which just calls `tr` to convert text to uppercase:

```
(defun test-shell-command (str)
  "Apply tr to STR to convert lowercase letters to uppercase."
  (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "*temp*")))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (insert str)
      (call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "tr" t t nil "'a-z'" "'A-Z'")
      (buffer-string))))
```

This function creates a temporary buffer, inserts the text, calls
`tr`, replaces the text with the result, and returns the result.

The above function works as expected, however, when I write a wrapper
around this function to apply the command to the region, two steps are
being added to the undo history.  Here's another example:

```
(defun test-shell-command-region (begin end)
  "Apply tr to region from BEGIN to END."
  (interactive "*r")
  (insert (test-shell-command (delete-and-extract-region begin end))))
```

When I call `M-x test-shell-command-on-region`, the region is replaced
with the uppercase text, but when I press `C-_` (`undo`), the first
step in the undo history is the state with the text deleted.  Going
two steps back, the original text is restored.

My question is, how does one prevent the intermediate step from being
added to the undo history?  I've read the [Emacs documentation on undo](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Undo.html),
but it doesn't seem to address this as far as I can tell.

Here's a function which accomplishes the same thing by calling the
built-in Emacs function `upcase`, just as before: on the result of
`delete-and-extract-region` with the result being handed off to
`insert`:

```
(defun test-upcase-region (begin end)
  "Apply upcase to region from BEGIN to END."
  (interactive "*r")
  (insert (upcase (delete-and-extract-region begin end))))
```

When calling `M-x test-upcase-region`, there is only one step in the
undo history, as expected.  So, it seems to be the case that calling
`test-shell-command` creates an undo boundary.  Can that be avoided
somehow?

Comment: The usual way to prevent the commands from cluttering the `(undo)` is to find a different way, one that does not do it. The example here is that you should almost never create a temporary buffer, but instead work with objects.

Comment: Other than manually reading and writing to temporary files, I'm not sure of another way to capture process output.  Even the asynchronous process commands like `start-process` seem to want to send the output to a buffer.

Comment: @JasonBlevins The fifth parameter to `shell-command-on-region` is REPLACE, so why do you need to wrap it?

Comment: @event_jr Good point: I wrote it this way to follow the "don't repeat yourself" principle, in order to have one function that returns a string and another that operates on the region, but without repeating the program name and arguments.  There are, of course, multiple ways to avoid repeating oneself, and your comment points to other good ways of structuring it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is the buffer name.  See [Maintaining Undo](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Maintaining-Undo.html#Maintaining-Undo):

> Recording of undo information in a newly created buffer is normally enabled to start with; but if the **buffer name starts with a space, the undo recording is initially disabled**. You can explicitly enable or disable undo recording with the following two functions, or by setting buffer-undo-list yourself.

`with-temp-buffer` creates a buffer named `␣*temp*` (note the leading whitespace), whereas your function uses `*temp*`.

To remove the undo boundary in your code, either use a buffer name with a leading space, or explicitly disable undo recoding in the temporary buffer with `buffer-disable-undo`.

But generally, use `with-temp-buffer`, really.  It's the standard way for such things in Emacs, making your intention clear to anyone who reads your code.  Also, `with-temp-buffer` tries hard to clean up the temporary buffer properly.

---

As for why undo in the temporary buffer creates an undo boundary in the current one:  If the previous change was undoable and made in some other buffer (the temporary one in this case), an implicit boundary is created.  From [`undo-boundary`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Undo.html#Undo):

> All buffer modifications **add a boundary** whenever the previous **undoable change** was made in some **other buffer**. This is to ensure that each command makes a boundary in each buffer where it makes changes.

Hence, inhibiting undo in the temporary buffer removes the undo boundary in the current buffer, too:  The previous change is simply not undoable anymore, and thus no implicit boundary is created.

Comment: I verified that using `(generate-new-buffer " *temp*")` in the original function works and that `with-temp-buffer` indeed creates a buffer whose name has a leading space.

I read that part of the documentation, but I didn't think that was the issue since undo information is specific to each buffer.  Why should I care whether undo information is recorded in the `*temp*` buffer?  But what I didn't gather from the documentation is that, apparently, the act of recording undo information in the other buffer must set an undo boundary in the current buffer.

Comment: @JasonBlevins An implicit boundary is created, if the previous change was undoable and made in some other buffer, in your case the temporary one.  I have edited my answer to explain the details.  Hopefully everything is clear now.

Answer (score 4):

There are many situations where using a temporary buffer is not practical. It's hard to debug what's going on for example.

In these cases you can let-bind `undo-inhibit-record-point` to prevent Emacs from deciding where to put boundaries:

```
(let ((undo-inhibit-record-point t))
  ;; Then record boundaries manually
  (undo-boundary)
  (do-lots-of-stuff)
  (undo-boundary))
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution in this case was to create the temporary output buffer
using `with-temp-buffer`, rather than explicitly creating one with
`generate-new-buffer`.  The following alternative version of the
first function does not create an undo boundary:

```
(defun test-shell-command (str)
  "Apply tr to STR to convert lowercase letters to uppercase."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert str)
    (call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "tr" t t nil "'a-z'" "'A-Z'")
    (buffer-string)))
```

I was not able to determine whether `generate-new-buffer` is indeed
creating the undo boundary, but this fixed the problem.
`generate-new-buffer` calls `get-buffer-create`, which is defined in
the C source code, but I could not quickly determine what was
happening in terms of the undo history.

I suspect that the issue may be related to the following passage in
the [Emacs Lisp Manual entry for `undo-boundary`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Undo.html):

> All buffer modifications add a boundary whenever the previous
>   undoable change was made in some other buffer.  This is to ensure
>   that each command makes a boundary in each buffer where it makes
>   changes.

Even though the `with-temp-buffer` macro calls `generate-new-buffer`
much as in the original function, the documentation for
`with-temp-buffer` states that no undo information is saved (even
though there is nothing in the Emacs Lisp source that suggests this
would be the case):

> By default, undo (see Undo) is not recorded in the buffer created by
>   this macro (but body can enable that, if needed).